# How to make Bresenham algorithm working backward?

Tags: c, bresenham

I got an exersise where I would like to draw a line with Bressenham algorithm.
The thing is that it's working perfectly for lines who goes down and on the right, but when the line goes up or backward, it doesn't work anymore ...
Does anybody can help me on that ?

```
void    draw_line(t_data img, int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd)

{
    int dx;
    int dy;
    int pk;
    int x;
    int y;

dx = xEnd - xStart;
dy = yEnd - yStart;
x = xStart;
y = yStart;

while(x <= xEnd)
{
    if(pk >= 0)
    {
        printf("in if ");
        my_mlx_pixel_put(&img, x, y, 0x00FF0000);
        y = y + 1;
        pk = pk + 2 * dy - 2 * dx;
    }
    else
    {
        my_mlx_pixel_put(&img, x, y, 0x00FF0000);
        pk = pk + 2 * dy;
    }
x = x + 1;
count ++;
}
}
```

Its working for this

```
draw_line(img, 300, 300, 400, 360);
```

But not for this

```
draw_line(img, 300, 300, 200, 260);
```

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: You don't initialize `pk`

Comment: `while(x <= xEnd)` Your code obviously expects `x` to be ascending. You could just swap coordinates if that is not the case. Then you only need to care if `y` needs to handle different cases

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for repyling. You mean swaping xEnd and xStart ?

Comment: and the y coordinate :)

Comment: Please see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) on the algorithm. Commonly you realize it just for one octant, and implement the other seven octants by other means.

Comment: @thebusybee that's for a circle!

Comment: No, it's about "Bresenham's line algorithm" as its title says. You can do circles with it, too.

Comment: You need to swap both, `x` and `y` together.

Comment: As busybee said, there are really eight cases: First, you must decide whether your principal axis is x or y, depending on whether |dx| < |dy|. Then you have the four combinations of ±dx and ±dy. Swapping the two points may help you, but you'll probably have to use abs or sign functions at some point.

Comment: @thebusybee oh: I see "you" was meant as "the OP", not "coders". For a circle, the other 7 are done by reflection, is what I thought you meant by "octant".

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, "octant" is the term in the Wikipedia page, as a mathematical term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in the first octant. If you want to draw lines in all direction you have to check the 8 octant.
here is my implentation of bresenham for the 8 octant:

```
void bresenham(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {    
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;

    int error;
    /** first quarter */
    if(dx >= 0 && dy >= 0) {
        /** 1st octant */
        if (dx >= dy) {
            error = -dx;
            int y = y1;
            for(int x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
                draw_pixel(x, y);
                error = error + 2 * dy;
                if (error >= 0) {
                    y++;
                    error = error - 2 * dx;
                }
            }
        }
        /** 2nd octant */
        else {
            error = -dy;
            int x = x1;
            for(int y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
                draw_pixel(x, y);
                error = error + 2 * dx;
                if (error >= 0) {
                    x++;
                    error = error - 2 * dy ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /** second quarter */
    else if (dx <= 0 && dy >= 0) {
        /** 4th octant */
        if(dx < -dy) {
            error = dx;
            int y = y1;
            for(int x = x1; x > x2; x--) {
                draw_pixel(x, y);
                error = error + 2 * dy;
                if (error >= 0) {
                    y++;
                    error = error + 2 * dx;
                }
            }
        }
        /** 3rd octant */
        else {
            error = -dy;
            int x = x1;
            for(int y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
                draw_pixel(x, y);
                error = error - 2 * dx;
                if (error >= 0) {
                    x--;
                    error = error - 2 * dy;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /** 3rd quarter */
    else if (dx <= 0 && dy <= 0) {
        /** 5th octant */
        if(dx <= dy) {
            error = 2 * dx;
            int y = y1;
            for(int x = x1; x > x2; x--) {
                draw_pixel(x, y);
                error = error - 2 * dy;
                if (error >= 0) {
                    y--;
                    error = error + 2 * dx;
                }
            }
        }
        /** 6th octant */
        else {
            error = 2 * dy;
            int x = x1;
            for(int y = y1; y > y2; y--) {
                draw_pixel(x, y);
                error = error - 2 * dx;
                if (error >= 0) {
                    x--;
                    error = error + 2 * dy ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* 4th quarter */
    else if(dx >= 0 && dy <= 0) {
        /** 7th octant */
        if(dx < -dy) {
            error = 2 * dy;
            int x = x1;
            for(int y = y1; y > y2; y--) {
                draw_pixel(x, y);
                error = error + 2 * dx;
                if (error >= 0) {
                    x++;
                    error = error + 2 * dy ;
                }
            }
        }
        /** 8th octant */
        else {
            error = -dx;
            int y = y1;
            for(int x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
                draw_pixel(x, y);
                error = error - 2 * dy;
                if (error >= 0) {
                    y--;
                    error = error - 2 * dx;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. Okay I get it !! thanks for your help and your time ! :)